# Java 10 code Deployment failed in Jenkins(Build is successful)

Tags: jenkins, java-10

I've updated my code Java 8 to Java 10. I'm trying to deploy that code in Jenkins after build successfully. But it's getting failed because of the following exception. It seems it's flyway jar version issue though I'm not sure about it.

- Where:
  Script '/var/www/soa-systems_denqa04/sysconfigservice/releases/detached_2018_07_24_15_49_54__0530__0f348d1d0545ded42325791260a4a32abd500af7/bootDeployment.gradle' line: 11
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.
  [33m> [39mFailed to apply plugin [id 'org.flywaydb.flyway']
  [33m> [39mCould not generate a proxy class for class org.flywaydb.gradle.task.FlywayValidateTask.

Comment: Please post the relevant code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: this is the code which having problem 
[ apply plugin: "org.flywaydb.flyway" ]
I'm having this line in my gradle file